# By using outlook calendar if we are declining appointment in outlook . then it will automatically decline in asp .net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone answer this question as soon as possible.

Code for Asp .net application and outlook:

```
public void MyMessage()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); // creates new outlook app
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); // creates a new appointment

    // Step 3 // Set appointment settings
    oAppointment.Subject = "Enquiry Changes made to " + "Appointment Fixed " + "'s enquiry"; // set the subject
    oAppointment.Body = "This is where the appointment body of the appointment is written"; // set the body
    oAppointment.Location = "Nicks Desk!"; // set the location
    oAppointment.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now); // Set the start date 
    oAppointment.End = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now); // End date 
    oAppointment.ReminderSet = true; // Set the reminder
    oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15; // reminder time
    oAppointment.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; // appointment importance
    oAppointment.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;


    //Step 4 // save the appointment
    oAppointment.Save();

    // Step 5 - Check your outlook calender
    //Appointment will now be added to your calender

    //Step 6 // send the details in email
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = oAppointment.ForwardAsVcal();
    // email address to send to 
    mailItem.To = "railwaydummy@gmail.com";
    // send 
    mailItem.Send();
}
```

I want code for if someone reject appointment in outlook then mail will send to user that your appointment rejected and it will reflect in asp application . Appointment rejected.

1.The recipient declines the invitation from Outlook Calendar - should trigger related rejection workflow in asp application

2.The recipient reschedules  the invitation through ASP application without going through the Outlook Calendar for a different date or time - automatic reschedule in Outlook

Comment: Just to check - you are aware that, if this code is running in an asp.net application, it's going to be automating Outlook on the *server*, not on the user's machine (this tends to go unnoticed when you're developing and the same machine is fulfilling both roles) - and also, automating Office apps from an asp.net application has never been supported.

Comment: Agree with the above comment. You might need two separate parts to the solution to achieve this - an asp.net application and an outlook add-in, which will handle the different parts. The add-in would have to keep outlook in sync with the application. Or, if you have Exchange 2016 then there are webservices which the application could interact with to achieve this server-to-server.